# Please explain where I made a mistake in this example $cos^2(x) - cos(2x) = \frac{1}{4}$

Tags: trigonometry

My solution:

$cos^2(x) - cos(2x) = \frac{1}{4}$

$cos^2(x) - (2cos^2(x) - 1)= \frac{1}{4}$

$cos^2x - 2cos^2(x) + 1 = \frac{1}{4}$

$-cos^2x=-\frac{3}{4}$

$cos^2x=\frac{3}{4}$

$cos(x) = \frac{\sqrt3}{2} \\  cos(x) = -\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$

x = $\frac{\pi}{6} + 2\pi n, n \in Z $

x = $\frac{11\pi}{6} + 2\pi n, n \in Z $

x = $\frac{5\pi}{6} + 2\pi n, n \in Z $

x = $\frac{7\pi}{6} + 2\pi n, n \in Z $

*I don't understand why the dots $\frac{11\pi}{6},  \frac{7\pi}{6}$ aren't included in the answer. Please explain)*

Comment: Use $\pi n$ instead of $2\pi n$ and the four answers combine into two

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, sorry, I peed myself, so my solution contains .../2

Comment: Your four solutions $\bmod{2\pi}$ are correct.

Comment: $cos(x)=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ corresponds to the $\pm(\frac{\pi}{6}+2\pi n)$ solutions, and $cos(x)=-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ corresponds to the $\pm(\frac{5\pi}{6}+2\pi n)$ solutions.

Comment: Whenever $-1\leq k<1$, we have two solutions of $cos(x)=k$ in the interval $[-\pi,\pi].$

Comment: @AaaLol_dude The OP is aware of that (your 2 comments).

Comment: The solution is $ \cos x = \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  \Rightarrow \quad x =k \pi \pm \frac{\pi}{6}$ where $k\in \mathbb Z$. $ \frac{11 \pi}{6}+2 \pi n =2 \pi(n+1)-\left(2 \pi-\frac{11 \pi}{6}\right)  =2 \pi m-\frac{\pi}{6}=k \pi-\frac{\pi}{6}$,  and $ \frac{7 \pi}{6}+2 \pi n =2 \pi n+\pi+\frac{\pi}{6} =\pi(2 n+1)+\frac{\pi}{6} =k \pi+\frac{\pi}{6} $